# How do I implement the np.argmin function for several dimensions

Tags: python, pandas, multidimensional-array, axis, np

I'm looking for help implementing logic without a loop for the following code. With the present / below code -4D array, I am facing issue since argmin takes just one axis, whereas I need to consider several axes.

```
array= np.array([270,480,9,9]) # 4 D shape
locs = np.argmin(array, axis=[2,3])
```

Error message:

> TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

and I do

```
i_y, i_x = np.unravel_index(locs , arry.shape[:2])
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] of `arry` and the matching expected output

Comment: I ve added a reproducible example